# update xtraTabbedMdiManager1 form's icon

Tags: c#, winforms, devexpress

I am working on an internet browser using xtraTabbedMdiManager and awesomium chrome browser. When the loadingFrameComplete ends I get the favicon from the website and replace the child form icon.

In a regular form app this works perfectly but I noticed in xtraTabbedMdiManager tab the icon will not change. The text changes but nothing else works. If anyone can help I will very much appreciate it. Below is the on loadingFrameComplete event..

```
private void Awesomium_Windows_Forms_WebControl_LoadingFrameComplete(object sender, Awesomium.Core.FrameEventArgs e)
    {
        Icon ic = GetFavicon(webControl1.Source.ToString());
        string strText = "";
        if (!webControl1.Title.ToString().Contains("about:blank"))
        {
            strText = webControl1.Title;
            if (strText.Length > 15)
            {
                strText = strText.Remove(15) + "...";
            }

            this.Text = strText;
            this.Icon = ic;//this icon should change...and it does if it was just a regular form
        }
    }
```

This is done inside the child form of the xtraTabbedMdi parent. Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you to specify images for tab pages directly via the [XtraMdiTabPage.Image](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#windowsforms/DevExpressXtraTabbedMdiXtraMdiTabPage_Imagetopic) or [XtraMdiTabPage.ImageIndex](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#windowsforms/DevExpressXtraTabbedMdiXtraMdiTabPage_ImageIndextopic) property and avoid using the `Form.Icon` property because the XtraTabbedMdiManager only using the `Form.Icon` for initialization of the XtraMdiTabPage.Image property and do not track changing of the `Form.Icon` property after that.

The pseudo-code:

```
xtraTabbedMdiManagerInstance.UseFormIconAsPageImage = DevExpress.Utils.DefaultBoolean.False;
//...
void Awesomium_Windows_Forms_WebControl_LoadingFrameComplete(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    Icon favicon = GetFavicon(...);
    xtraTabbedMdiManagerInstance.Pages[this].Image = favicon.ToBitmap();

}
```